# Can't read database in Android assets

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've a database named HOSPITALS.db with 97 entries and 8 columns. [I tried following this](http://www.geeks.gallery/read-and-copy-database-from-assets-folder/).

But it produced an error of

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mariel.paths/com.example.mariel.paths.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: hospitalList (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM hospitalList

```
dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    dbHelper.openDataBase();
    hosp = new Hospitals();
    hosp = dbHelper.Get_ContactDetails();

    ArrayList<OverlayItem> anotherOverlayItemArray = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < hosp.getHospName().size(); i++){
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem("Road", "Nodes", new GeoPoint(hosp.getLatitude().get(i), hosp.getLongitude().get(i))));
    }

    ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> anotherItemizedIconOverlay
            = new ItemizedIconOverlay<>(
            this, anotherOverlayItemArray, null);
    map.getOverlays().add(anotherItemizedIconOverlay);
    dbHelper.close();
```

Hospitals.java

```
public class Hospitals {
    public List<String> hosp_name = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Double> longitude = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Double> latitude = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getHospName() {
        return hosp_name;
    }

    public void setName(List<String> hosp_name) {
        this.hosp_name = hosp_name;
    }

    public List<Double> getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(List<Double> latitude){
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public List<Double> getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude() {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    // constructor
    public Hospitals (List<String> hosp_name, List<Double> latitude, List<Double> longitude){
        this.hosp_name = hosp_name;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public Hospitals (){
    }
}
```

DataBaseHelper.java

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // All Static variables
// Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HOSPITALS.db";
    private static final String DB_PATH_SUFFIX = "/databases/";
    static Context ctx;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        ctx = context;
    }

    // Getting single contact
    public Hospitals Get_ContactDetails() {


       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM hospitalList", null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
           hosp_name.add(cursor.getString(1));
           latitude.add(cursor.getDouble(6));
           longitude.add(cursor.getDouble(7));
           cursor.close();
           db.close();
        }
        Hospitals cont = new Hospitals(hosp_name, latitude, longitude);
        return cont;
    }

    public void CopyDataBaseFromAsset() throws IOException{

        InputStream myInput = ctx.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = getDatabasePath();

        // if the path doesn't exist first, create it
        File f = new File(ctx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX);
        if (!f.exists())
            f.mkdir();

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }
    private static String getDatabasePath() {
        return ctx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX
                + DATABASE_NAME;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        File dbFile = ctx.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);

        if (!dbFile.exists()) {
            try {
                CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
                System.out.println("Copying sucess from Assets folder");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);
            }
        }

        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/) instead.

Comment: please check your database, is there any  `hospitalList` named table?

Comment: @Basi i have the table

Comment: apparently what i am missing is `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"` but it's still not executing.

Comment: it means no table,  check your DB using DB viewer like SQLite browser

Comment: @Basi i already checked and the tablename is right